# Letting DLL crash instead of application

Tags: c++, windows, dll

I'm developing multiple DLLs which are used by an app. The features of this app and DLLs are modularized and each of them can work as standalone (i.e.: app only, app + DDL_1, app + DLL_1 + DLL_2, etc.).

Now whenever a DLL crashes (i.e.: NULL-pointer, stack overflow, etc.), the whole app crashes. Is there a way to let only the DLL crash, in which the exception occurred? I'm managing the DLLs but not the app.

### Update

I'm aware that the DLL itself does not crash, as it is only code which is loaded into the app. What I wanted to know is, if there is a way to exclude the specific features of that DLL at runtime, if something in it goes wrong.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can't afaik.. A dll is loaded into the virtual memory of the current application. If the dll crashes, so does the app..

Comment: Dll is just a file with code, it can not crash. It is process executing dll code that crashes.

Comment: Your question shows a lack of understanding of how a multitasking OS operates which is the real problem here, I think. I would recommend to you that you learn what processes are in a multitasking OS, the difference between a process and a thread, and what is address-space separation before doing anything else. You really do need the theoretical foundations.

Comment: @VTT : That sounds like a full answer.  (With the *minor* caveat that one might be able to arrange for just a thread to crash.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to call the DLL as a child process, rather than dynamically link against it. Which require a separate wrapper application capable of some form of IPC to your parent process.

DLLs linked against your main application will cause the stack pointer and base pointer to shift into the address space of the DLL loaded into memory at runtime. Which means if it crashes in the DLL, the main application itself will crash. The DLL itself is not what is "crashing". It's the main application operating with the functions stored in the DLL.